# How to grab text in page source?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a product database for an existing online website and need to grab the product description.

I am able to manually go into the page source and copy the description, but I wanted to know if there is a way to parse the page source/pipe it into a text file and then grab what I need out of it.

I have the item number for each product which I can construct the URL that links to the product's page with all of the information.

I have tried using curl and piping the output to a text file, however the text file itself shows nothing written into it. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Example of what I am hoping to grab:

> (textarea name="txtDescription" rows="10" cols="20" readonly="readonly"
>   id="txtDescription"
>   style="color:Gray;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;font-size:Small;height:135px;width:400px;")
>   PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE (/textarea)

Comment: There are many ways to do this from a server-side script. You need to be more specific.

Comment: If you're referring to Amazon, then you'll have lots of fun. A while ago, they had the descriptions loaded dynamically with JS (and I guess they are still doing it. Anyway, if it's static, have you tried anything at all? :)

Comment: Have a look at PhantomJS, there are many examples and tools, for example http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/